# Использование CompletableFuture блокирует главный поток

Tags: android, kotlin, concurrency, future, completablefuture

Я хочу использовать средства java.util.concurrent для организации асинхронности для долгих операций, которые возвращают значение. Я пытаюсь использовать для этого CompletableFuture. Сделал такой код для симуляции вызова:

```
class MyRepository {

    private var counter = 0

    // Here we make a blocking call
    fun makeRequest(): Int {
        Thread.sleep(2000L)
        counter += 1
        return counter
    }
}
```

И затем я вызываю этот метод из UI потока:

```
fun getNumber(): Int {
    val completableFuture = CompletableFuture<Int>()
    Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit<Any?> {
        val result = myRepository.makeRequest()
        completableFuture.complete(result)
        null
    }
    return completableFuture.get()
}
```

Проблема в том, что UI приложения всё равно блокируется на время выполнения этих операций. В чем ошибка в моем коде и как сделать так, чтобы UI поток не блокировался на время работы метода?

Я хочу использовать именно средства java.util.concurrent, это в учебных целях.

Comment: Ошибка в самом подходе: асинхронный метод по определению не может возвращать результат, так как результат будет получен после выхода из метода в другом потоке. И для того чтобы вернуть результат, вы сделали метод синхронным, используя блокирующий вызов `Future.get()`. Асинхронный вызов должен строиться из рабочего потока и колбека, в который будет передан результат через очередь нужного потока. Я бы посоветовал корутины, раз уж на котлине пишете, но я их знаю очень издалека.

Comment: `Future` для этого не особо подходит - нужен еще один поток, который будет ждать результат и после получения перекидывать его в главный поток, и там вызывать колбек, который уже сделает с результатом что-то полезное.

Comment: Возвращать надо `completableFuture`, а извлекать из него значение - только *после* завершения.

Comment: А как извлечь из `completableFuture` значение после завершения?

Comment: Вызовом `completableFuture.get()`.

Answer (score -1):

`CompletableFuture.get()` - это блокирующий (синхронный метод) - поэтому UI и блокируется.

Вам нужно использовать `runAsync()`, который принимает на входе поток в котором и будет работать ваш `CompletableFuture`.

Чтобы получить значение которое вычислить ваш `Completable` - надо организовать слушателя, в который и надо передавать значение из `runAsync()`

В Android обычно это старый добрый `LiveData` или более модный сейчас `StateFlow`